# Intune Management Extension not installing - download mirror doesn't exist

Tags: azure, mdm, intune

I have two laptops with Intune that both received commands to the EnterpriseDesktopAppManagement CSP to download the Intune Management Extension but Intune gave them bad mirrors. They were told to download the Intune Management Extension from https://prodamsua0402rcdata.azureedge.net/IntuneWindowsAgent.msi but it doesn't download because the mirror doesn't exist. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recently experienced the same issue and opened up a case with Microsoft. Posted about this on Technet too: https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/98f996f2-07eb-4a6a-b6b5-64a18d465117/intune-management-extension-fails-to-download-and-install-with-error-downloadfailed?forum=microsoftintuneprod

There are incorrect URLs being distributed to download the IntuneWindowsAgent.msi from. If you remove 'rc' from the URL (https://prodamsua0402data.azureedge.net/IntuneWindowsAgent.msi
), you can successfully resolve and download the agent manually.

As a workaround you can install the Intune Management Extension by running the MSI manually on the affected machines.

To have this fixed for your tenant you will need to open up a support case with Microsoft.

Comment: Awesome. Thanks!

Comment: I had opened up a case with Microsoft about this but they claimed it was my fault for using Win32 apps, which is a preview feature. I told them the CDN mirror did not exist but they ignored me. I read your post on technet and it looks like you did the same exact research I did but like I said Microsoft just ignored everything I said about the CDN mirror.